# Only Cyrillic input text form

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I restrict input text into a web form textbox only **Cyrillic** characters?

Comment: What are the Cyrillic characters

Comment: @polin абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюя

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you should use encoding which supports Cyrillic characters (e.g. UTF-8) both for page and for scripts. Then, you may use regular expression to check:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^а-яё]/i, "");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CSjkP/

Comment: I'd stay away from ranges for anything non-Latin. In this particular example you've just excluded "ё" from correct letters.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Thanks for 'Ё', I skipped it. Regarding ranges, character range represents underlying range of encoding table values, where the alphabet always goes as it goes. 'Ё' character is an additional sign, which can be added manually.

Comment: This works, of course, but it does not help when the user "copy->past" text or pressed and hold any key.

Comment: @SevadaGhazaryan You may add `paste` event (which is not cross browser) or simply use `change` event. It works only after focusing out, but has no compatibility problems.

Comment: @VisioN thanks, basically at the moment this variant (use change event) though somehow useful for me!

Comment: @VisioN, not it is not "always goes as it goes". ё is going between e and ж since 1918 and is out of its rightful place only thanks to stupid limitations dating back to typewriters.

Answer (score 3):

Use any of many available JS form validators (a simple search will get you dozen) with regexp that only matches Cyrillic:

```
/^[абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯ]*$/
```

Maybe you would also like to add space or numbers there.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
   var verified = String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[a-zA-Z-]/);
   if (verified) {
  e.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/fejkmzp1/1/