# How to get the entire input value dynamically (not the last character only)?

Tags: jquery

There's the input that I want to validate with jquery. The problem is that jquery seems to be only using the last input character, excluding the characters that had been input before.
Please take a look at my short code fragment.

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input#signup_fname_input", function () {
    var this_user_input = $("input[name='signup_fname_input']").val();
    var onlytext_regexp = /[A-zА-яЁё]+$/;
    if ((!onlytext_regexp.test(this_user_input)) && (this_user_input !== '') || (this_user_input.indexOf("[") != "-1") || (this_user_input.indexOf("]") != "-1") || (this_user_input.indexOf("\\") != "-1")) {
        $('#feedback_message_signup1').css({
            "visibility": "visible",
            "color": "#CC0000"
        });
        $('#feedback_message_signup1').html("Недопустимый символ");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm confused.  In the `on` statement, you say `signup_fname_input` is the ID of the input field, but later you are specifying it as the Name of the field.  Is it both, or one or the other?

Comment: The ID and the Name are identical for that element.

Comment: I have a feeling that the error might be caused by the regexp variable. What I wanted it to do was to verify whether the input was exclusively alphabeetical in latin and cyrillic charsets. Is there any possibility that it might have instead been verifying whether THE LAST CHAR was alphabetical only excluding the chars input before that last char?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. Clearly your problem isn't that you are only getting the last character, you can prove that by logging the value you pulled using .val()

Comment: It definitely seems to be the regex, though I'm not too familiar with it and can't answer your question.  However I would suggest basing the `var this_user_input` off of the ID since that is what you used above as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, I removed the string values from the if-condition. This is meant to be some kind of if(not valid), right?

```
$(document).on('keyup', "input#signup_fname_input", function () {
    var this_user_input = $("input[id='signup_fname_input']").val();
    var onlytext_regexp = /^[A-zа-яёЁ]+$/;
    if ((!onlytext_regexp.test(this_user_input) && this_user_input !== '') || this_user_input.indexOf("[") !== -1 || this_user_input.indexOf("]") !== -1 || this_user_input.indexOf("\\") !== -1) {
        $('#feedback_message_signup1').css({
            "visibility": "visible",
            "color": "#CC0000"
        });
        $('#feedback_message_signup1').html("Недопустимый символ");
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe just use /^[A-zа-яёЁ]+$/   ? Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138715/only-cyrillic-input-text-form

Comment: if you want to allow spaces, you should use /^[A-zа-яёЁ ]+$/

Comment: Let me try this, I'm still not sure whether its the regex that causes the error or not. Thanks.

Comment: There are two issues with your regex pattern: Firstly, you forgot to add the ^ at the beginning. this is why only the last characters were checked, or to say: you did not check the entire input. Secondly, your cyrill check did not seem to be correct. Still, I am not used to cyrillic letters and I should be careful before I judge ;) hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, now everything is working properly :)